# How to change Directadmin.inc.php to support ssl login

Tags: php, api, directadmin

There is a script called Directadmin.class.php that has written years ago.
I use it to create email. 
after force my panel to use ssl, the following code does not work any more:

```
$da = new DirectAdmin('domain.de', 'cookies/',"http://11.11.11.11:2222", '$username', "$passwd");
```

I change it to

```
$da = new DirectAdmin('domain.de', 'cookies/',"https://11.11.11.11:2222", '$username', "$passwd");
```

but not work again.

Directadmin.inc.php

```
<?php
/**
* DirectAdmin File
* Object Class to interact with DirectAdmin (http://www.directadmin.com/)
* Web Pannels
* 
* @author Hadar Porat <hpman28@gmail.com>
* @version 1.5
* GNU Lesser General Public License (Version 2, June 1991)
*
* This program is free software; you can redistribute
* it and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU
* Lesser General Public License as published by the Free
* Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License,
* or (at your option) any later version.
*
* This program is distributed in the hope that it will
* be useful, but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the
* implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
* PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU Lesser General Public License
* for more details.
*/
/**
* DirectAdmin Class
* @access public
* @author Hadar Porat <hpman28@gmail.com>
* @version 1.5
*/
class DirectAdmin {
    private $ch;
    private $cookiePath;

    /**
    * @return void
    * @param string $domain domain name
    * @param string $cookiePath temp location to save cookie
    * @param string $url url of directadmin
    * @param string $username directadmin username
    * @param string $password directadmin password
    * @desc class constructor
    */      
    function __construct($domain, $cookiePath, $url, $username, $password) {
        $this -> data = array (
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $password,
        'referer' => '/',
        );
        $this -> domain = $domain;
        $this -> params = array();
        $this -> url = $url;
        $this -> setCookiePath($cookiePath);
        $this -> setCommand('CMD_LOGIN');
        $this -> executeCommand();
    }
    /**
    * @return void
    * @param string $path cookie path
    * @desc set the cookie path
    */      
    function setCookiePath($path) {
        $this -> cookiePath = $path;
        $this -> cookieFile = 'cookie_' . rand(0, 1000) . '.txt';
        fopen($path . $this -> cookieFile, 'w+');
    }
    /**
    * @return void
    * @param string $command command name
    * @param string $params paramters for the command
    * @desc set the directadmin command
    */  
    function setCommand($command, $params = '') {
        $this -> command = $this -> url . $command;
    }
    /**
    * @return void
    * @param string $command command name
    * @param string $params paramters for the command
    * @desc set the directadmin command for a certain domain action
    */      
    function setDomainCommand($command, $params = '') {
        $this -> command = $this -> url . $command . '?domain=' . $this -> domain;
        if (is_array($params)) {
            $this -> data = array_merge($this -> data, $params);
        }
    }
    /**
    * @return void
    * @desc execute the command
    */      
    function executeCommand() {

        $this -> ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($this -> ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($this -> ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($this -> ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  array('Accept: application/json', 'X-HTTP-Method-Override: POST'));
        curl_setopt($this -> ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
        curl_setopt($this -> ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this -> cookiePath . $this -> cookieFile);  //initiates cookie file if needed
        curl_setopt($this -> ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this -> cookiePath . $this -> cookieFile);  // Uses cookies from previous session if exist
        curl_setopt($this -> ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this -> command);
        curl_setopt($this -> ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $this -> data);
        curl_setopt($this -> ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($this -> ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        curl_setopt ($this -> ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        curl_setopt ($this -> ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
        $result = curl_exec($this -> ch);


        if(curl_errno($this -> ch)){ 
          echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($this -> ch); 
        } 
        curl_close($this -> ch); 
        return $result;
    }
    /**
    * @return void
    * @desc get stats array
    */      
    function getStats() {
        $this -> setCommand('');
        $html = $this -> executeCommand();
        preg_match_all("/<td width=\"3[3-4]%\" class=bar-row[1-2] align=\"center\">(.*?)<\/td>/", $html, $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
        $array = array(
        'used' => array('diskspace' => $out[1][0], 'bandwidth' => $out[1][2], 'emails' => $out[1][4], 'ftp' => $out[1][6], 'database' => $out[1][8]),
        'max' => array('diskspace' => $out[1][1], 'bandwidth' => $out[1][3], 'emails' => $out[1][5], 'ftp' => $out[1][7], 'database' => $out[1][9]),
        );
        return $array;
    }
    /**
    * @return void
    * @param string $username new account username
    * @param string $email account email
    * @param string $password new account password
    * @param string $domain account domain
    * @param string $package account package
    * @param string $ip ip address 
    * @desc create a new user account
    */  

    /**
    * @return void
    * @param string $username account username
    * @param string $password account password
    * @desc modify account to auto package
    */      
    function modifyUserAccountPackage($username, $package) {
        $this -> setDomainCommand('CMD_MODIFY_USER', array('action' => 'package', 'user' => $username, 'package' => 'auto'));
        $this -> executeCommand();
    }
    /**
    * @return void
    * @param string $username account username
    * @param string $vdomains virtual domains number
    * @param string $bandwidth bandwidth allowed
    * @param string $quota disk quota
    * @param string $mysql mysql database number
    * @desc customize account package
    */      
    function customizeUserAccountPackage($username, $vdomains, $bandwidth, $quota, $mysql) {
        $this -> setDomainCommand('CMD_MODIFY_USER', array('action' => 'customize', 'user' => $username, 'php' => 'ON', 'unemails' => 'unlimited', 'vdomains' => $vdomains, 'bandwidth' => $bandwidth, 'quota' => $quota, 'mysql' => $mysql));
        $this -> executeCommand();
    }
    /**
    * @return void
    * @param string $name database name
    * @param string $username account username
    * @param string $password mysql database number
    * @desc creates a new mysql database
    */      

    /**
    * @return void
    * @param string $domain domain name
    * @param boolean $database include databases in backup
    * @param boolean $email include emails in backup
    * @param boolean $ftp include ftp in backup
    * @param boolean $ftpsettings include ftp settings in backup
    * @desc creates a account backup
    */          


    /**
    * @return void
    * @param string $filename backup filename
    * @desc chmod a account backup for downloading
    */  
    function chmodBackup($filename) {
        $this -> setDomainCommand('CMD_FILE_MANAGER', array('action' => 'multiple', 'button' => 'permission', 'permission' => '1', 'chmod' => 777, 'path' => '/backups', 'select0' => '/backups/' . $filename));
        $this -> executeCommand();
    }       

    /**
    * @return void
    * @desc returns backups array list
    */      
    function getBackupsList() {
        $this -> setDomainCommand('CMD_FILE_MANAGER/backups');
        $html = $this -> executeCommand();
        preg_match_all("/<td class=list[2]?>(.*?)<img border=0 alt=\"File\" src=\"\/IMG_FILE\"><\/a><\/td ><td class=list[2]?>(.*?)<\/td ><td class=list[2]?>(.*?)<\/td ><td class=list[2]?>(.*?)<\/td ><td class=list[2]?>(.*?)<\/td ><td class=list[2]?>(.*?)<\/td >/", $html, $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
        $array = array();
        for ($i=0;$i<count($out[0]);$i++) {
            $array[] = array('filename' => strip_tags($out[2][$i]), 'size' => strip_tags($out[3][$i]), 'timeStamp' => strtotime(strip_tags($out[6][$i])));
        }
        return $array;
    }
    /**
    * @return void
    * @desc returns email accounts array list
    */      
    function getEmailList() {
        $this -> setDomainCommand('CMD_EMAIL_POP');
        $html = $this -> executeCommand();

        preg_match_all("/<td class=list[2]?>(.*?)<\/td ><td class=list[2]?>(.*?)<\/td ><td class=list[2]?>(.*?)<\/td >/", $html, $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
        $array = array();
        for ($i=0;$i<count($out[0]);$i++) {
            $out[5][$i] = explode('@', $out[2][$i]);
            $array[$out[5][$i][0]] = array('email' => $out[1][$i], 'username' => $out[2][$i], 'boxname' => $out[5][$i][0], 'quota' => $out[3][$i]);
        }
        return $array;
    }
    /**
    * @return void
    * @param string $username email account username
    * @desc returns email account information
    */          
    function getEmail($username) {
        $array = $this -> getEmailList();
        return $array[$username];
    }
    /**
    * @return void
    * @param string $username email username
    * @param string $password email password
    * @param string $quota emailbox size
    * @desc creates new email account
    */      
    function createEmail($username, $password, $quota,$limit) {
        $this -> setDomainCommand('CMD_EMAIL_POP', array('action' => 'create', 'domain' => $this -> domain, 'user' => $username, 'passwd' => $password, 'passwd2' => $password, 'quota' => $quota, 'limit' => $limit));
        $this -> executeCommand();
    }
    /**
    * @return void
    * @param string $username email username
    * @param string $password new email password
    * @desc updates emailbox password
    */      
    function updateEmail($username, $password) {
        $this -> setDomainCommand('CMD_EMAIL_POP', array('action' => 'modify', 'domain' => $this -> domain, 'user' => $username, 'passwd' => $password, 'passwd2' => $password));
        $this -> executeCommand();
    }
    /**
    * @return void
    * @param string $username email username
    * @desc deletes email account
    */  
    function deleteEmail($username) {
        $this -> setDomainCommand('CMD_EMAIL_POP', array('action' => 'delete', 'domain' => $this -> domain, 'select1' => $username));
        $this -> executeCommand();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Check if apache on 11.11.11.11 has configured ssl correctly, check if your php has openssl installed

Comment: I can login to my panel throw https://11.11.11.11:2222

Comment: What about openssl?

Comment: I should check it. but script use curl when I can connect to it by my browser , curl should connect too

Comment: If you don't have openssl installed in php, you won't be able to make https call to any website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was faced this situation last year, check yor server ip in black listed Directadmin.
directadmin php 5.6 in already compiled with openssl. don't worry about that.